# Bitbake no encuentra un archivo .tar.gz de una receta Yocto

Tags: linux, yocto

Estoy recetando una distribución Yocto linux para incluir la VPN Wireguard. El caso es que construyendo la receta fsl-image-full de freescale, intenta descargar un archivo .tar.gz y no está disponible ni lo encuentro en ningun lado. Su mirror tampoco parece estar disponible.

Como estoy detrás de un proxy restringido, el archivo que se descarga es texto plano, indicando que no se encuentra ese archivo, ese texto plano, se guarda con el nombre del paquete python-enum34-1.0.4.tar.gz dentro del directorio downloads. Cuando se intenta descomprimir logicamente no coinciden lo datos MD5 esperados.

La pregunta es ¿Donde puedo encontrar este archivo python-enum34-1.0.4.tar.gz?
Aqui el log del error.

```
DEBUG: Executing python function base_do_fetch

DEBUG: Mirror fetch failure for url http://git.freescale.com/source/python-enum34-1.0.4.tar.gz (original url: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/source/$/python-enum34/python-enum34-1.0.4.tar.gz)
DEBUG: Fetcher failure: Fetch command failed with exit code 4, output:
Read error (Connection timed out) in headers.
```

Comment: Está rarísimo que intente descargar eso del git de freescale, pues ese paquete está [disponible](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/python-enum34-1.0.4-1.el7.noarch.rpm.html) en la mayoría de repos oficiales; es el soporte para enumeraciones (que se añadió en python 3.4)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero lo que necesito es el .tar.gz no el rpm. ¿Podría construir mi propio .tar.gz a partir del rpm? ¿Podría modificar la receta de bitbake para que yo instale con yum por ejemplo? Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Workaround.
Convertir el .rpm en .tar.gz

```
cp foo.rpm /var/tmp/
cd /var/tmp
mkdir foo
cd foo
rpm2cpio ../foo.rpm | cpio -idmB
cd ..
tar -zcf foo.tar.gz foo/
```